# Frequent Disconnects on Linux

Tags: networking

I have problems with my internet connection on a Debian Linux Distribution (Zorin OS). I am connected to the router with an ethernet cable.

They do not occur with windows on the same hardware and do not happen from a specific trigger as far as I can tell but seem random. I suspect that every now and then the connection to the router is lost for a second or so. These are the problems that manifest:

- Downloads will almost never finish on the first try. I usually need to restart them every 2-3 times because there was a "network error"
- Chrome regularly (almost every second page I open) shows an error "ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED". It always works after a reload.
- SSE connections are always dropped after a few seconds even though the reconnect always works flawlessly
- ssh-connections to my server are constantly dropped with the error packet_write_wait: Connection to myserver-ip port 22: Broken pipe

Unfortunately I have no idea how to further debug or fix this problem since I can't even consistently replicate it.

Comment: I'll blame a misconfigured MTU. Try a smaller MTU, e.g. 1400 B, and report back!

Comment: How is your system connected to internet ?

Comment: I am connected via Ethernet cable. I did not install any other network managers on purpose, is there a way I can check whether multiple are configured?

Comment: Does your PC has the same IP address with Linux as when you start it with Windows? Please check. If the IP addresses differ, then the reason might be that Linux is using an IP address that is already used on your network: try setting the same IP address that is used with Windows and see if the issue still occurs.